# My marker is not geocalised on React-Leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have created a hook component with React JS for geolocalised my marker at starting application.
The currentLocation value as change but the marker don't move. You know why ?

```
import { useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { useMap } from "react-leaflet";
import L from "leaflet";

import icon from "./../constants/iconPosition";

export default function LocationMarker() {
  const map = useMap();
  let [currentPosition, setCurrentPosition] = useState([48.856614, 2.3522219]);

  useEffect(() => {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
      setCurrentPosition([position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude]);
    })
    let latlng = currentPosition;
    L.marker(latlng, { icon }).addTo(map).bindPopup("You are here!");
    map.panTo(latlng);
  }
},[]);

  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the the latlng of the marker in `getCurrentPosition` function:

```
 if (navigator.geolocation) {
    
    let latlng = currentPosition;
    var marker = L.marker(latlng, { icon }).addTo(map).bindPopup("You are here!");
    map.panTo(latlng);
    
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
      var pos = [position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude];
      setCurrentPosition(pos);
      marker.setLatLng(pos);
      map.panTo(pos);
    })
  }
```

Comment: It's correct, thank you but the terminal display a new message: "React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'currentPosition' and 'map'. Either include them or remove the dependency array" at the end of useEffect in the array.